# Node dependencies

Tags: ros, nodes, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Is there a simple way to create a dependency graph between ROS nodes? I would like to build a graph-like data structure where the presence of an edge between two nodes of the graph (representing ROS nodes) means that one of the nodes subscribes to a topic that the other node publishes, or that one of the nodes requests a service that the other node provides.

Any information on this would be highly appreciated !

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206355/node-dependencies/) by [kobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/22042/kobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-03-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Afaik it cannot visualise service dependencies, but [rqt_graph](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_graph) should get you at least the pub/sub connections that exist:

[rqt_graph http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_graph?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=snap_rqt_graph_moveit_demo.png](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_graph?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=snap_rqt_graph_moveit_demo.png)

For build system level dependencies, see [rospack](http://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rospkg/html/rospack.html), and in particular `rospack depends ..` and [roseco](http://http404error.github.io/roseco/).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2